# How to execute python string in linux terminal?

Tags: python, linux, string, terminal, execute

I am really new in programming and sorry if my question is not nicely formulated. I will try with time to be more precise.

I just stepped into the programmer world and already stacked :)

What I am trying to do is next: I want to execute or start or run (not sure how to say it) string that I get with python. Here is my small script and what I want to do is to automatically run gotten string in the linux terminal. Here is the script:

```
barcode = raw_input("Please insert the barcode for DECK 1 PAL:")
formula = "./bmdcapture -C 0 -m 1 -F nut -f pipe:1 | ffmpeg -i - -c:v prores -profile:v 3 -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 384k -vf yadif -map 0 /path/to/file/" + barcode + ".mov"
print(formula)
```

What I should add to automatically start gotten string after input?

Thank you all.
Zoran

Comment: Is there some reason that you want to do this with Python rather than just doing it directly with Bash?

Comment: You should check out reddit.com/r/learnpython, it's a bit more beginner friendly than stackoverflow. Don't get me wrong, this site rocks once you learn how it works, but often beginner questions are bashed a bit too hard.

Comment: PM 2Ring: The only reason why I want to do it with Python is that I am learning it and want to practice it. If you know how to do it with Bash please let me know so I can try it?

Comment: Markus Meskanen: Thank you so much for advice. I will check it out and learn more. I am at the very beginning and I lear fast by doing the things. So that is the reason why I am here.